# FMXBroadcastReceiver (Android) is broken in Delphi 10 Seattle? What changed since XE7?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

To work with USB-devices (on Android-devices having USB-host) one has to use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).
I have found a demo (https://github.com/freeonterminate/delphi/tree/master/BroadcastReceiver). I have tested it on Delphi XE10. Wasted a lot of time to make it work until I discovered that demo works on XE7 but not on XE10.

"Interface not supported" error is occured during JFMXBroadcastReceiver creation (or near).

To demonstrate the problem I have created a brand new simple project https://github.com/ashumkin/Delphi-Android-BroadcastSample.
It works in XE7 (press "Register" button to create a broadcast receiver which catches and logs (see adb logcat) screen locking/unlocking. But it does not work in XE10 - "Interface not supported" occurs.
In logcat I can see

```
W/dalvikvm(31735): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/embarcadero/firemonkey/broadcast/FMXBroadcastReceiverListener'
W/dalvikvm(31735): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/embarcadero/firemonkey/broadcast/FMXBroadcastReceiver'
```

(but they are present in logcat of XE7-built app)

I tried to remove XE7 version of `AndroidManifest.template.xml`, created .dproj-file in XE10, - nothing helps!.

WTF?

Thanks!

Comment: In 10.1 Berlin (not 10.0 Seattle), you can receive a broadcasted Android `Intent` using [`IFMXApplicationEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXApplicationEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler) and [`TMessageManager.SubscribeToMessage()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessageManager.SubscribeToMessage) to process [`TMessageReceivedNotification`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/List_of_FireMonkey_Message_Types#FMX.Platform.TMessageReceivedNotification.Android) messages.

Comment: See Embarcadero's [AndroidIntents](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Berlin/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Snippets/AndroidIntents/) examples.

Comment: BTW, there is no XE10!  Get that out of your head. There is 10.0 Seattle, 10.1 Berlin, etc. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: I use the following component working also in 10.0: https://github.com/barisatalay/delphi-android-broadcast-receiver-component

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you're right about XE10 ) I mean and use Delphi 10 Seattle.
Will try TMessageReceivedNotification, but I doubt that it is.

Comment: @AndreRuebel, baritasalay's component actually is almost the same (by code) as the component from the mentioned demo https://github.com/freeonterminate/delphi/tree/master/BroadcastReceiver...
But I've checked it now (applied demos) and unfortunately, It does not work for me, too :( I mean it works from XE7 and does not from Delphi 10

Comment: @AndreRuebel Wow! Debug config works! Release does not!

Comment: @RemyLebeau, using TMessageReceivedNotification does not suite here,  Digging into FMXNativeActivity + OnActivityListener (decompiling fmx.jar classes) shows actual events that are converted into TMessageReceivedNotification message.

Comment: I have to admit that I never tried the component I mentioned in a release build since I use it in an app only designed for myself. Strange that it makes a difference.

Comment: @AndreRuebel, It seems https://github.com/barisatalay/delphi-android-broadcast-receiver-component component differs from https://github.com/freeonterminate/delphi/tree/master/BroadcastReceiver, though, in some details... First does work in Delphi 10!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/barisatalay/delphi-android-broadcast-receiver-component works in Delphi 10!
It has differences in details from https://github.com/freeonterminate/delphi/tree/master/BroadcastReceiver, but there are important for working, as I can see.